# Connecting to Oracle from SSIS on Vista 64 bit

Tags: ssis

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB using SSIS on Vista 64 bit and getting the following error.
"Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.
Provider is unable to function until these components are installed."

I am using the Oracle 10.2.0.4 64 bit compatible client.

However, on a 32 bit machine I am able to successfully connect to Oracle source using a 10g 32 bit compatible client.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the required version of the Oracle client could not be located.

If you are attempting to make the connection to Oracle from within the Business Intelligence Design Studio on the 64-bit machine you will also need to install the 32-bit Oracle client, since BIDS is a 32-bit application.

Comment: Yup. See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387868/oracle-install-for-ssis-connectivity-and-drivers-32-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Oracle client 32bit & 64bit both version..

Please refer to the link:
http://knol.google.com/k/jeyong-park/accessing-oracle-data-source-from-64bit/3vywlm4f31xae/12

Answer (score 0):

Choose Run-Time when install the Oracle client which will give you Net Manager to set up TNSNames and such. 32 Bit Client for Windows