# Oracle Install for SSIS connectivity (and drivers 32 64 bit)

Tags: oracle, ssis, driver

I have an SSIS package (SQL 2008) that I need to connecto to an Oracle DB (11g) with. What do I need to install to connect to oracle? What's the terminology ? All searches I've done talk about Instant Client, but on downloading that I see no exe's? I know installing the server will give me that Oracle Net manager (UI to update TNSNames.ora) but I don't want to install the entire server. That to be is overkill. What's the smallest footprint so that I can create a connection to an oracle DB via my Connection Manager in SSIS?

Also what's the difference between *Instant Client* & *Oracle Client tools* etc? There's so much arcane (atleast to me) terminology that it's confusing.

P.s. - From reading http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html you would think this was what I wanted, but the download just has an install.bat that seems to do nothing! Typical of the "solutions" I've tried so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, what I did was download **Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)** from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html. It had 4 options for installing One of them being Instant Client(which did not help me). The one that works is **Runtime client** or something named like that. It installs Net Manager which is what I want.

PS-Adding on (as I traverse the Oracle 64 bit journey), I find that I cannot use SSIS with 64 bit oracle DB providers. I get the exceptions (on adding a connection in SSIS):

> Test connection failed because of an
>   error in initializing provider.
>   Attempt to load Oracle client
>   libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatException.  This problem
>   will occur when running in 64 bit mode
>   with the 32 bit Oracle client
>   components installed.

I'm guessing this is because SSIS process is a 32 bit one and cannot use 64 bit oracle drivers (my host machine is Win 7 64 bit).

After testing, I found that this is indeed the case. **We need the 32 bit drivers only for the SSIS IDE** but can use 64 bit when running the DTSX package using the 64 bit dtexec.exe (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn)

So in DEVELOPMENT (on a 64 bit machine) install both the 32 and 64 bit clients:
32 bit: for development in Visual Studio IDE
64 bit: To run the DTSX package using the 64 bit version of dtexec.exe on the command line (as would be the case when we run this in a production environment)

A similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067727/connecting-to-oracle-from-ssis-on-vista-64-bit).

Comment: Related link: http://knol.google.com/k/accessing-oracle-from-64bit-sql-server-or-ssis#

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the difference between the Install Client and the Oracle Client Tools.  I've always used the latter.  The link below has a download for the 10g client tools (under Oracle Database 10g Client Release 2), which should be what you require to get the connectivity from SSIS.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204-winx64-vista-win2k8-082253.html

Comment: how do you connect this to SSIS? after downloading i see a bunch of files including adrci.exe, genezi.exe and uidrvci.exe. not clear of how to make this driver show up in SSIS import package

Answer (score 1):

I used this link [Configuring SSIS 2008 to Connect to Oracle](http://jerryaspnet.blogspot.com/2012/05/configuring-ssis-2008-to-connect-to.html) and was successful getting VS 2012 to use SSIS with Oracle 11.2 instantclient.  All credit to the author, Jerry Dy.  NOTE: The only registry entry required is the one for ORACLE_HOME.