# Oracle connections broken in SSIS after uninstalling 32bit version of oracle client

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl, oracleclient, oraoledb

I get the following error message when I try to test my connections:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

I originally had 32 bit and 64 bit version of Oracle 12 client installed on my work machine. I uninstalled the 32bit version, because it was causing some conflicts with another application, but now after uninstalling I can no longer use my oracle connections in SSIS.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 - I am pretty sure I installed 64bit version of SSDT, but it looks like they install under the 86x programs folder. I can still connect via TOAD, so it looks to be an issue of SSIS not pointing to the 64bit installation, I think. Can I manually set SSIS to point to the 64bit version, or do I need to reinstall 32bit?

TSN_Admin is set to the oracle12c_64 tsnname.ora file. I have also tried using the regsvr32.exe on oraoledb12.dll file, but I get an error message, even after running command prompt as admin:

> The Module "OraOLEDB.dll" was loaded by the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005.

I can reinstall the the 32bit version, but I need to wait for my company's IT department to approve the request first. It could be days before I get a response.

Comment: What's the "Run64BitRuntime" option set to? Click Project -> Properties.   Then at the left under "Configuration Options" click on Debugging and you'll see that option.

Comment: Forgot to mention that. I tried setting that property from false to true, but there was not change.

Comment: It is not related to `Run64BitRuntime`, check my answer for more details

Comment: TOAD uses only the core oci.dll but not the OLE DB driver (or any other driver as ODBC or Oracle Data Provider for .NET). TOAD is available for 32-bit and 64-bit, check which version you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 1 - Visual Studio 64-bit

After searching it looks like there is not Visual Studio 64-bit version:

- [Visual Studio 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit)

---

## Initial Answer

I don't know if there is an official documentation for this, but based on my own experience **you need to instal oracle client 32-bit on the developpement machine**, because **SQL Server Data Tools for Visual studio is a 32-bit application** and it will not work will work with oracle client 64-bit.

But you can execute .dtsx package without any issue if you are working with oracle 64-bit client, you need to use the appropriate DtExec path:

**32-bit**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DtExec.exe
```

**64-bit**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DtExec.exe
```

While searching, i found many other links that share the same opinion:

- [Oracle Install for SSIS connectivity (and drivers 32 64 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387868/oracle-install-for-ssis-connectivity-and-drivers-32-64-bit)
- [Oracle Client Provider for OLE DB in SSIS not working](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/72772c16-19a6-4c42-a23f-676f17fcf1d5/oracle-client-provider-for-ole-db-in-ssis-not-working?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Connecting to Oracle 11g on 64-bit (x64) machine SSIS 2012](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2e365f0-45cc-43f0-be70-9358701387a2/connecting-to-oracle-11g-on-64bit-x64-machine-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thank you for this post. I was able to get 32 bit reinstalled, which rectified all the issues I was having with ssis in visual studio. Good to know vs relies strictly on 32bit oracle.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio is 32 bit. Thus you also need a 32-bit Oracle Client - at least if you like to use built-in wizards etc. If you compile your application as 64bit then you need the 64-bit Oracle Client.